# parsing html page using php to find out text on which link is assiged

Tags: php

say i have html code like this

```
$html = "This is some stuff right here. <a href='index.html'>Check this out!</a> <a href=herp.html>And this is another thing!</a> <a href=\"derp.html\">OH MY GOSH</a>";
```

i am trying to get values of href and also on which anchor work i mean check this out text i am able to get href value by following this code

```
$displaybody->find('a ') as $element;
echo $element;
```

well it works for me but how do i get value of check this out could you guys help me out. i did search but i am not able to find it out . thanks in advance

my actual html look like this

```
<a href="www.myurl/point.html" class="l" style="color:#436DBA;" onclick="return rs(this,'8 Stunning Linguistic Miracles of The Holy Quran | Kinetic Typography 144p (Video Only).mp4');">&raquo; Download MP4 &laquo;</a> - <b>144p (Video Only)</b> - <span> 19.1</span> MB<br />
```

my href look like this above code return download mp4 and i want it like downloadmp4 114p (video only) 19.1 mb how do i do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are using now is the [`SimpleHTMLDOM`](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), then `->innertext` works fine on that anchor elements that you have found:

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = "This is some stuff right here. <a href='index.html'>Check this out!</a> <a href=herp.html>And this is another thing!</a> <a href=\"derp.html\">OH MY GOSH</a>";

$displaybody = str_get_html($html);
foreach($displaybody->find('a ') as $element) {
    echo $element->innertext . '<br/>';
}
```

If you were referring to PHP's [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), then its not `find()` function you need to use, to target each anchor element, you need to use `->getElementsByTagName()`, then each selected elements you need to use `->nodeValue`:

```
$html = "This is some stuff right here. <a href='index.html'>Check this out!</a> <a href=herp.html>And this is another thing!</a> <a href=\"derp.html\">OH MY GOSH</a>";

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $element) {
    echo $element->nodeValue . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Oh my. I've been lost in javascript for too long. I didn't know PHP got so smart when it comes to the DOM. But isn't this "native" to PHP5 instead of using a library ? http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: @user1735121 you could choose either one of them, but i suggest use `DOMDocument` instead, since you do not need to use an external library as `DOMDocument` is already built-in within PHP. anyways, im glad this helped

Comment: <a href="www.myurl/point.html" class="l" style="color:#436DBA;" onclick="return rs(this,'8 Stunning Linguistic Miracles of The Holy Quran | Kinetic Typography 144p (Video Only).mp4');">&raquo; Download MP4 &laquo;</a> - <b>144p (Video Only)</b> - <span> 19.1</span> MB<br />  my href look like this above code return download mp4 and i want it like downloadmp4 114p (video only) 19.1 mb how do i do that

Comment: if you want to use `DOMDocument`, since you wanted the simple text just target straight thru the body, `echo $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->textContent;`

Comment: i am using simple html dom how i get it i have updated the question check once please